# Getting a type error when I try to use the sum function

Tags: python, sum, int, callable

Here is my code:

```py
even = (i for i in range(20) if i % 2 == 0)
sum(even)
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error, instead of getting 90:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

What did I do incorrectly in my code?

Comment: are you sure you are getting that error? I just run it and I got 90.

Comment: It sounds like you used `sum` as a variable earlier in your code and over-wrote the builtin. This is why you often hear people telling you not to use `list` or `str` as a variable name.

Comment: You probably have a variable somewhere else called `range` or `sum` that is shadowing the builtins.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code or some portion above to this. I am suspecting some over-written bultin function

Comment: I just ran it in a separate file and it worked. But in the original file, where I have already executed a few lines of code, it gives me that TypeError, but I didn't call any variable "even" elsewhere.

Comment: A line of code that I'm suspecting might be an issue is this

results = [city + ': ' + year for city,year in zip(cities,years) if int(year) > 1945]
results[:10]

which is similar, but it doesn't produce an error.

Comment: Okay! All i did was clear and restart the all output, and then rerunning it from the start produced no errors. It's very strange. But I started writing the code for this particular file a few weeks ago, and just rand this line of code today, so maybe it was caused by that? I don't understand why there was a problem in the first place and why it worked after restarting the kernel.

Comment: @Narek Please post complete code, esp the sum function. This will help you get quick and quality answers.